# TODAY Function in Excel with automatically update

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good morning...

Anyone tell me how to get today function automatically update in Excel without open file. I want to use it for news ticker in VMIX.

I use `=TODAY()` but not updated when i dont open it.

Thanks

Comment: There should be an outside program that does it. For example, you may run the python code in the background.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: reference the system date & time - no need to open the file then.